# Email Popup window for feedback in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wanted to create a popup email window for my project. I got this git repo https://github.com/ya332/react-feedback-popup
Wanted to use this but with some modification in UI. How can I do that? How to integrate in my project?

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: Check the installation and usage section of the repository: `npm install --save react-feedback-popup`

Comment: @ajvg94 Yes I installed in my app and it is working. But I wanted to change the react-feedback-popup UI and then wanted to install it in my app.  How can I do that?